# How to load balance AWS private subnet EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy, amazon-elb

If I create an ELB and try to attach the private subnet instances, my health check fails: OutOfService.

Question 1 : Can I get a internal / private IP(not IP but dns name) for Load Balancing. i.e not accessible to the internet?

Question 2 : If I have a public dnsname for my Application Load Balancer. How do I attach EC2 instances that are in my private subnet without an Elastic IP(aren't internet accessible). 
I am looking for the best approach. Should we have-

ELB --> public subnet EC2 instances (proxy configuration- */*  [private_ip]:[port]/* ) ---> Service from Private Subnet/EC2 instance with health checks here.

Answer (score 8):

The traditional architecture is:

- Elastic Load Balancer in **public subnet**
- Amazon EC2 instances in **private subnet**
- **Security group on Load Balancer** permitting port 80 & 443 from `0.0.0.0/0`
- **Security group on instances** permitting port 80 from the *Load Balancer security group*
- An Amazon Route 53 Hosted Zone with a `CNAME` record set pointing to the DNS Name of the Load Balancer

If your instances are failing the Load Balancer health check, check the following:

- The instances should have a security group permitting inbound access from the Load Balancer
- The Load Balancer health check should be configured with a path to a web page to use for the health check
- The instances should have a functioning web server that is responding to the health checks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an ELB, I would recommend using Auto Scaling Group to put instances in various AZ/subnets.
Look at this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-register-lbs-with-asg.html).  The benefit of having an ASG that you can optionally also have scale in/our policies.

The archiceture that you have described ELB (Assuming this is public) -> public EC2 instances (as Proxies) -> Private EC2 instances.

Rather you can have your Private EC2 instances fronted with a ELB. Not sure if you really need the public EC2 instances.

If your health check is failing you need to ensure that:

a. You are creating the ELB in the right VPC.

b. The ELB -> EC2 communication is setup correctly by ensuring you have the right [Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#vpc-security-groups) in place on the EC2 instances.
A highly recommended way would be to have the EC2 instances SG rules setup in such way that they accept traffic only from the SG of the ELB.