# AWS: Why is a public IP required for load-balancing to my private subnet EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am trying to have an Internet-facing ELB load balance incoming traffic to my private subnet EC2 instances. My Load Balancing Target group reports that my EC2 instances are unhealthy even though they passed all checks on the EC2 page.

**What I do not understand is that**: If I do attach a Network Interface AND a public IP to my private subnet EC2 instances, then everything works. At the end of the day, my Security Groups still prevent direct external access to my instances but I do not believe public IP addresses are required because I understand load balancers to work with internal IP addresses. So what am I not understanding correctly here? Much thanks in advance.

My security/network settings are as follows:

- Route tables: /16 VPC CIDR to Local, 0.0.0.0/0 to Internet Gateway, Implicitly associated with all subnets
- NACL: (For testing purposes), Allow all to everywhere for both inbound and outbound, Associated with all subnets
- Security group of private subnet EC2 instances allow incoming traffic from Load Balancer SG only and allow all outbound traffic.
- Security group of Load Balancer allow incoming traffic from anywhere, and allow all outbound traffic.

The closest thread I could find is this:[How to load balance AWS private subnet EC2 instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619409/how-to-load-balance-aws-private-subnet-ec2-instances) but I've checked through all the items without success.

Comment: Can you ssh to the EC2 instance and verify that your application is working? You will need to use bastion host in public subnet  as a jump instance.

Answer (score 1):

What is the Private Subnet?

Ans- `Private Subnet is - the subnet which does not have route to Internet Gateway.`

Route to internet Gateway is the only thing which decides whether it is public subnet or private subnet.

but `your subnet is having route to internet gateway`, that means your subnet is public subnet and public subnet needs public IP.

`In your situation your subnet is not private subnet`. and also Internet facing ELB means you are looking to accept connection/request from Internet.

To make it private subnet remove route to Internet Gateway. and use NAT Gateway if you need internet to your instance , or use Bastion instance if you need to SSH your instance