# Load Balancer Issues when AWS Windows EC2 is in private subnet but website in IIS needs to be accessible from a public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Windows EC2 is in private subnet. NAT is configured with internet gateway to allow internet access of this private subnet. Session Manager is configured. EC2 instance is running with default website in IIS on port 80 and 443. Port 80 and 443 are allowed in security group.

Put a Load Balancer in a public subnet and configure it to forward HTTP/S requests to the EC2 instance in the private subnet. Associated the public subnets with EC2 load balancer.   Registered the EC2 instances with your load balancer. Targets groups are created for this. Health status port is 80 and 443. While configuring load balancer, I have specified my org DNS myorg.int.com, and validated the same successfully.

Now, when I am calling https://myorg.int.com, I am expecting to view default website running on EC2 in IIS

However its not working.

Also, health status is showing unhealthy

Comment: Is myorg.int.com an internal only hostname? Or, was it an "example" hostname? I ask because when I do a nslookup of that hostname, I'm not getting an IP address.

Comment: Its dummy name provided here as an example

Comment: Have you followed the traditional ELB setup described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619409/how-to-load-balance-aws-private-subnet-ec2-instances?rq=2 If your health status is showing unhealthy, that would imply that the last step didn't work as expected (i.e. the load balancer can't communicate with the EC2 instance.)